# Regular Expression in CAtlRegExp format not working?

Tags: c++, regex, mfc, atl

I created a regular expression to capture Microsoft Office executables like so:

```
 .*(\\Microsoft Office\\Office)(\d){1,2}(\\)(WINWORD.EXE|EXCEL.EXE|POWERPNT.EXE|MSACCESS.EXE|OUTLOOK.EXE|VISIO.EXE|WINPROJ.EXE)$
```

Anyway it turns out that the software I'm using only supports the CAtlRegExp flavour of regular expressions, and the above does not work.

I'm looking at the following article for reference and using the tool to test my regular expression:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13320/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-MFC

An example path is:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE

Can anybody assist?

Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing `(\d){1,2}` with `\d\d?`. Also, it makes sense to escape all `.` before extensions. Try `.*\\Microsoft Office\\Office\d\d?\\(WINWORD|EXCEL|POWERPNT|MSACCESS|OUTLOOK|VISIO|WINPROJ)\.EXE$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may use

```
.*\\Microsoft Office\\Office\d\d?\\((WINWORD)|(EXCEL)|(POWERPNT)|(MSACCESS)|(OUTLOOK)|(VISIO)|(WINPROJ))\.EXE$
```

The point here is that all alternatives inside `(...)` must be also wrapped with parentheses and that the regex flavor does not support limited (interval) quantifiers, and `{...}` defines a *capturing group* with zero-based IDs. `\d\d?` matches 1 or 2 digits. See the [docs you refer to](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13320/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-MFC):

> You can note that the syntax is not exactly the same as in Perl. For example, **the grouping operator is {}, while in Perl it is (), and it doesn't have the {n} (match exactly n times) as in the Perl syntax**

Also note that a literal dot should be defined with `\.` and it is a good idea to only use one `\.EXE` after all the grouped alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to match when I test it in the tool I referred to.  I've even tried to strip it down to this, and it still doesn't work?

(WINWORD|EXCEL|POWERPNT|MSACCESS|OUTLOOK|VISIO|WINPROJ)\.EXE$

Comment: @Captain_Planet It is strange because the documentation mentions that `|` is an alternation operator, but `|` does not seem to work in that demo app.

Comment: @Captain_Planet Just got "Success match" with `.*\\Microsoft Office\\Office\d\d?\\((WINWORD)|(EXCEL)|(POWERPNT)|(MSACCESS)|(OUTLOOK)|(VISIO)|(WINPROJ))\.EXE$`. Please test in the target environment.

Comment: Brilliant - that works!  Can you edit your answer (above) so I can mark it as an answer?  Thanks!